# Python: Not able to read first row of csv file correctly using read_csv

Tags: python, csv

Trying to read the csv file through pandas, but it looks like it is not reading it correctly

Code:

```
pd.read_csv(data_file_path, sep=",", index_col=0, header=0, dtype = object)
```

For eg: My data is (in csv file):

```
12 1.43E+19 This is first line  101010  
23 1.43E+19 This is the second line 202020  
34 1.43E+19 This is the third line  303030
```

I am trying to read with first column as index.

Output:

```
     1.43E+19 This is first line    101010  
12  
23 1.43E+19 This is the second line 202020  
34 1.43E+19 This is the third line 303030
```

Output without making 1st column as index:

```
  12 1.43E+19 This is first line 101010  
0 23 1.43E+19 This is the second line 202020  
1 34 1.43E+19 This is the third line 303030
```

Because of this, any further processing on this data is ignoring the first row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing `header=0`, which means "use the 0-th row as the header", with `header=None`, which means "don't read a header from the file".

Compare:

```
>>> pd.read_csv("h.csv", header=0, index_col=0)
        1.43E+19       This is first line  101010  
12                                                 
23  1.430000e+19  This is the second line    202020
34  1.430000e+19   This is the third line    303030
>>> pd.read_csv("h.csv", header=None, index_col=0)
               1                        2       3
0                                                
12  1.430000e+19       This is first line  101010
23  1.430000e+19  This is the second line  202020
34  1.430000e+19   This is the third line  303030
```

You can also specify column names using `names`:

```
>>> pd.read_csv("h.csv", names=["Number", "Line", "Code"], index_col=0)
          Number                     Line    Code
12  1.430000e+19       This is first line  101010
23  1.430000e+19  This is the second line  202020
34  1.430000e+19   This is the third line  303030
```

---

PS: Since you're using `sep=","` but the file you showed doesn't have any commas, I'm assuming that you removed them for some reason when asking the question.  If that's right, please don't: no one's afraid of commas, and it simply means that other people have to guess where to put them back in if they want to test your code.

Comment: Aah.. I see. I thought header = 0 means "No header". My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. The code is working now. And I am reading data from csv file so copied the data directly from file to show here. Sorry for confusion.